# WP Query and multiple queries

Tags: wp-query

I have a registration form that I'm trying to put limits on sign ups for specific characters. I've added fields for each character with a checkbox. I have this code that I'm working through that's just driving me nuts.. It errors out as I add anything past two queries.. I will say I'm an old guy that does this as a hobby I'm far from a professional. :) and still learning.

```
$args = apply_filters( 'event_manager_custom_event_registrations_args', array(
'post_type' => 'event_registration',
'post_status' => array_diff( array_merge( array_keys( get_event_registration_statuses() ), array( 'publish' ) ), array( 'archived' ) ),
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
'posts_per_page' => '-1',
'post_parent' => $event_id
) );
//Registration Query
//_registration_limit is a field name
//change the number to your limitation of attendees
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$registration_limit = get_post_meta($event_id,'_darth_vader',true);
if($registration_limit >= 1 && $the_query->found_posts >= $registration_limit ){
return false;
}
return true;
}
$the_query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
$registration_limit = get_post_meta($event_id,'_boba_fett',true);
if($registration_limit >= 1 && $the_query2->found_posts >= $registration_limit ){
return false;
}
return true;
}
//Here is where it breaks with a syntax error
$the_query3 = new WP_Query( $args3 );
$registration_limit = get_post_meta($event_id,'_emperor',true);
if($registration_limit >= 1 && $the_query3->found_posts >= $registration_limit ){
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Part of me feels like this is an older code that is doing it based on what I can find. Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is args2 and args3? Are they defined anywhere?

Comment: The code you show us is invalid. It has two closing curly brackets which never where opened.

Comment: your code is ugly formatted. and i agree on @max, i guess after return false, you are missing the `else {`..?

Comment: The args2 and args3 along with the rest are all looking at fields in the registration form. So defined? I think so. I fixed the curly brackets and added the else statement. Seems to be working now. As for the formatting, yea it looks much better in notepad++ than on here.

Comment: Thanks All I knew it was a forest and trees thing.